# small plus button in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to have small plus or minus button before each row in a table,as shown in the image below.I am a beginner to jqm,please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post any html i'll assume that your elements are buttons, which is the easy way of setting icons. So, your element is a link with a data-role=button. Then you add the data icon="plus" and data iconpos="notext" to hide text content.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true">ButtonTitleIsNotShown</a>
```

Comment: Thanks , but I don't want the text "ButtonTitle" in the button.just the small + icon.when I m providing nothing between <a></a> still its a wide button,not just the icon